# "incorrect mount option was specified" when mounting krb5p nfs4 partition on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, kerberos, nfsv4

I have a NFS4 share running with krb5p.

I have no problems accessing it from CentOS clients, all that is required is:

```
yum install krb5-workstation
setup krb5 (edit krb5.conf, setup keytab)
systemctl enable nfs-secure.service && systemctl start nfs-secure.service
systemctl enable nfs-client.target && systemctl start nfs-client.target
mkdir /mnt/x
Add the following to fstab:
server.example.com:/srv/share/subdir /mnt/x nfs4 defaults,sec=krb5p,noexec,nosuid,_netdev,auto     0       0
```

This works great on CentOS, I've setup a dozen client hosts so far that way.  However on Ubuntu, I get :
`mount.nfs4: an incorrect mount option was specified`

I think the Ubuntu error is to do with `nfs-secure.service` however there seems to be no equivalent on Ubuntu that gets installed with NFS client ? (I am using Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS).

***UPDATE:***

I have tried:
`systemctl enable rpc-gssd.service && systemctl start rpc-gssd.service`

That launches OK:

```
# systemctl status rpc-gssd.service
● rpc-gssd.service - RPC security service for NFS client and server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rpc-gssd.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-10-04 16:49:40 BST; 6min ago
  Process: 51689 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rpc.gssd $GSSDARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 51691 (rpc.gssd)
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 516.0K
      CPU: 13ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/rpc-gssd.service
           └─51691 /usr/sbin/rpc.gssd
```

But Ubuntu just hangs when trying to mount ?

```
 # mount -v -t nfs4 -o defaults,sec=krb5p,noexec,nosuid,_netdev,auto server.example.com:/srv/dir/example /mnt/example
mount.nfs4: timeout set for Thu Oct  4 16:54:40 2018
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5p,addr=10.10.10.10,clientaddr=10.10.10.9'
# NOTHING ELSE HAPPENS.....
```

Comment: Have you configured `/etc/default/nfs-common/` and then reloaded nfs-common?

Comment: @sebasth is that a requirement on Ubuntu ?  Never had to do that on CentOS ? Are you saying I need to set "NEED_GSSD=" in `/etc/default/nfs-common` ?  But woudl that not be the same thing as `systemctl enable rpc-gssd.service && systemctl start rpc-gssd.service` ?

Comment: `NEED_IDMAPD` and `NEED_GSSD` both probably should be turned on. I would expect Ubuntu NFS be configured via `/etc/default/nfs-common` as on Debian (the files likely had been removed if they weren't used/required).

Comment: @sebasth unfortunatley no change with those options enabled. ;-(

Comment: You restart `nfs-common` as well? You can also increase verbosity for mount by adding more `-v` options.

Comment: @sebasth `systemctl` isn't listing an `nfs-common` service, only `nfs-config.service` and `nfs-client.target`, I have restarted `nfs-client` but unsure where `nfs-common` is ?  `nfs-common` is definitley installed : `nfs-common/xenial-updates,now 1:1.2.8-9ubuntu12.1 amd64 [installed]`.  Adding verbosity does nothing, it just gives me two lines: `mount.nfs4: timeout set for` and `mount.nfs4: trying text-based options` ... no further verbosity.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a generic error message (also totally misleading), which points towards a problem in your client kerberos configuration, usually that the GSSAPI service isn't running. Try starting it, or if you have a nss-client.target, enable/start it.